# Why doesn't the stack trace get printed?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, stack-trace

While trying to print the `stack trace` in my browser window, I fail. Following is the sample of the exception block.

```
try {
    // Add Code Here
} catch(Exception exc) { exc.printStackTrace();}
```

I am using `google app engine` as my server. What could be the reason the stack trace is not printing ?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `Exception` to catch:

```
try {
    // Add Code Here
}
```

You will only print a stack trace an `Exception` is thrown within the `try` block like this:

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method in question is implemented like this:

```
public void printStackTrace() {
    printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

If your container/IDE/framework redirects the stream then you will not observe it at the expected location, see also `System.setErr(...);`. And of course, I expect you to have checked that your code really throws an `Exception` (if an `Error` then it will not be caught by your clause).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the default error output stream. Since you are most probably coding a `servlet` , you could change to :

```
exc.printStackTrace(response.getWriter());
```

This will print the exception trace into the browser window.